# I cant get the value from an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dynamic, url-parameters

When I try to get the value from fakeData it shows undefined in foodDetails. But other show output correctly.
if I put static data then it shows value like this
const foodDetails = foodFakeData.find(pd => pd.id === 101);
but if I put "foodId" then it shows undefined why?
In console.log('foodDetails',foodId, foodDetails) shows "foodDetails 112 undefined"

```
const FoodDetails = () => {
const { foodId} = useParams();
const foodDetails = foodFakeData.find(pd => pd.id === foodId);
console.log('foodDetails',foodId, foodDetails);
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Hello {foodId}</h3>
        </div>
    );
};
export default FoodDetails;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `foodId` from `useParams` was undefined? Simply use useEffect in combination with `useState` to control `foodDetails`.

```
const [foodDetails, setFoodDetails] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  if(foodId) {
    setFoodDetails(foodFakeData.find(pd => pd.id === foodId));
  }
}, [foodId]);
```

Comment: foodId in log show output but undefined in foodDetails, that the problem that I can't understand.

Comment: It works now, I have added toString method, Thank you